# How to add a property to NgForm values

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I currently have an Angular form that returns the form values using (ngSubmit). I want to add another property to, lets say an input, where I can specify a search operator like (contains, equal, starts with, etc).

How can I get the operator with the values from the form?

Here's an example. I added `operator` to both inputs. I'd like to return this in the form value when search is called. Is there a custom directive I could write or a way to extend form values?

```
<form #searchForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="search(searchForm)">
    <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" operator="contains" />
    <input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" operator="equal" />
</form>

search(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
}
```

So I would get something like this back or be able to bind to that operator.

```
name: { value: 'John', operator: 'contains' }
```

Comment: And the operator for name (for example) is always "contains"? The user can't select which operator he wants?

Comment: Yes, That's how I'd like it to work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the appropriate model. The operator doesn't need to be in the view:

```
this.model = {
  name: {
    value: '',
    operator: 'contains'
  },
  email: {
    value: '',
    operator: 'equal'
  }
};

search() {
  console.log(this.model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name.value" />
  <input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email.value" />
</form>
```

Comment: Indeed this is a simple approach that works, just wondering if the definition of a sub property of the model that doesn't change could be avoided...

Comment: It could. But then you would have to transform the model (using a Map<propertyName, operator>) before sending the request. It's a valid option, but a tiny bit more complex. The main point is that this doesn't need to be in the view. This also prepares for the moment when the user will have to choose the operator, and it will thus have to be in the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native javascript to achieve this:

```
search(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('my-input');
    console.log(element.getAttribute('operator'));
}
```

and:

```
<form #searchForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="search(searchForm)">
    <input type="text" id="my-input" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" operator="contains" />
    <input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" operator="equal" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can't have it be a part of the form itself though, unless you add another input below it, like a radio button or something. To me, that makes more sense than how I did it above.